# Restricting generic function to only work on Enums

Tags: c#

I have the following generic function:

```
public SomeType SomeFunction<T>(T value)
{
}
```

I would now like to restrict this generic function to work only with `Enum`s so I tried the following:

```
public SomeType SomeFunction<T>(T value) where T : System.Enum
{
}
```

But this resulted in:

> error CS0702: Constraint cannot be
>   special class 'System.Enum'

Is there a work around and out of curiosity does anyone know the reason why this type of constraint isn't allowed?

Comment: You should take a look at the accepted answer in the dupe mentioned by Ani. This is a restriction of the C# language, not the CLR (for example, it's possible to constrain to `enum` in F#). The Unconstrained Melody library provides a workaround to allow `enum` constraints in C# itself: http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. You can restrict it to value types, but that's all. Restricting it to enums can only be done using runtime checking:

```
public SomeType SomeFunction<T>(T value) where T : struct
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Only enums are supported.");
    }
}
```

Comment: +1.  It's also worth noting that System.Enum isn't an enum.

Comment: The problem is that I have another, non generic, function with the same name that's not being called now because all calls to `SomeFunction` get routed to the generic version, gah!

Comment: You can actually make the constraint a little tighter too, not that it really helps much: `where T : struct, IComparable, IConvertible, IFormattable`

Comment: @Moo-Juice: Is System.Enum not an enum, the same way System.ValueType isn't a value type?

Comment: @Matt correct.  System.ValueType is merely a container for when a value-type is boxed so is therefore useless as a generic parameter.  And System.Enum derives from it :)

Answer (score 1):

Steven is correct, but you can narrow it a little before you throw an exception

```
public SomeType SomeFunction<T>(T value) where T : struct
```

Comment: That's less than what Steven said. -1

Comment: The -1 is not deserved, because I edited my answer to add the `where T : struct` later on. This edit possibly crossed this post.

Comment: Ok, but (according to SO timekeeping) you answered 5 minutes after Steven. You both must have done ninja edits if you're saying that your answer had more info than Steven's at some point, because I can't see any edits to either answer. Sorry if this is the case.